# When do you use std::unordered_map::emplace_hint?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, unordered-map

I know how to use `std::unordered_map::emplace`, but how do I use `emplace_hint`? Neither [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace_hint/) nor [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace_hint) provide a set of examples that illustrate how we might know where to put the element.

Can anyone provide some information on this or give some examples / illustrations of when we might know where the emplaced element should go?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What could an `unordered_map` potentially do with the hint?  Well, if the iterator addresses an element with the same key as the element that `emplace_hint` has been asked to insert, then it can fail quickly - just a key comparison without any hashing or groping through any list of hash-colliding elements at that bucket.  But if the key doesn't match, then the hint is otherwise useless because any other key - no matter how "close" in value - should (probabilistically) be at a completely unrelated bucket (given what's normally considered a "good" hash function), so time would have been wasted on a key comparison only to have to start over as if it were a normal `emplace`.

This might be useful when you're inserting pre-sorted-by-key elements, aiming to remove lots of duplicates in the process, but the key is so huge it's easier to keep an iterator to the just-inserted element than a copy of the key, or perhaps the hash function is particularly slow.

Another benefit of `unordered_map::emplace_hint` is better API compatibility with `map::emplace_hint`, so code can switch the container type and have the `emplace_hint`s not break the compile, though they might end up slower than if the code were switched to `emplace()` as the close-but-different-key hints that help with a `map` may be useless with an `unordered_map`.

---

Just taking GCC 10.2 `g++ -E` output to see if it does what's described above.  `emplace_hint` calls down into `_M_insert_multi_node(...)` wherein there's this line:

```
__node_base* __prev = __builtin_expect(__hint != nullptr, false)
                      && this->_M_equals(__k, __code, __hint)
                      ? __hint
                      : _M_find_before_node(__bkt, __k, __code);
```

Above, `__k` is the key that may be inserted, `__code` is the hash code, `__hint` is the hint iterator/pointer; `_M_equals(...)` returns:

```
return _Equal_hash_code<__node_type>::_S_equals(__c, *__n) &&
       _M_eq()(__k, this->_M_extract()(__n->_M_v()));
```

So, it's checking that the hash codes are equal (a quick and dirty check if you've already calculated the hashes) and the keys are equal (a potentially slower operation for e.g. a quality hash of long strings) before using the hint iterator.  That's the only case in which it uses the hint.  Imagine the bucket logically has some colliding elements chained off it with keys K1, K2, K3, K4 and your hint iterator is to K4 but you're trying to insert a duplicate with K2: as the iterators are *forward only*, you have to use `_M_find_before_node(...)` to reach colliding elements earlier in the chain than your hint points to.  After the `_M_find_before_node(...)` you can scan from K1 forwards to see if the key to insert - K2 - is already present in the elements that collided at the bucket.

(The implementation could be improved by skipping the hash comparison when the key comparison is known to be cheap, but getting that condition right with type traits would be a bit of a pain - how do you know which key equality functions are cheap?  Could assume so for small, standard layout, trivially copyable types or similar, at least when the unordered container is instantiated with the default `std::equals<>` comparison....).

Comment: I didn't get this answer completely.. perhaps it's because of how it's worded. So it's useless unless I have pre-ordered multiple keys?

Comment: @Dean: you don't necessarily have to have "pre-ordered multiple keys" - it could be that the order in which they naturally occur means repeated keys have a high enough probability of occurring in succession to make keeping around an iterator to the last-emplaced value worthwhile, as you could quickly reject the duplicate.  Still, this is all based on the only possible use of the hint I can think of - if your implementation doesn't actually use the hint, you're wasting time and effort supplying it.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if there was a function which would return an iterator to the element (if found) or a valid hint (if not found) - similar to how you can use `lower_bound` to search or generate a hint for a `map`.

Comment: @user253751: there's already [`insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign) and [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) for when the find attempt would be immediately followed by an insertion or update, but yes - having something helping you separate the two in time may be good sometimes: the most useful thing though would be to keep the bucket number around and use that to avoid hashing; you can't have an iterator to a specific bucket & some buckets lack elements - so an iterator hint's awkward.

Comment: I'm wondering about integral keys when an `unordered_map` is populated from a sorted source, such as a file. I'm thinking there would be no advantage with `emplace_hint` in that case, but I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @EmileCormier: it depends... if there may be duplicate integral keys side-by-side in the sorted source, then yes - the hint may help.  Otherwise (i.e. if the integral keys are all distinct), then the hint will not help.

Comment: The hint absolutely doesn't make any sense. The buckets are chosen absolutely randomly according to the key with a decent hash-function, so there wouldn't be any correspondence between two different keys. Of course this is different for unordered_multimap, where multiple equal keys are mapped to the same bucket. But for unordered_map emplace_hint is a pure nonsense-API.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: well - you got halfway there.  As you say, there's no correspondence between different keys, so the hint is only potentially useful for quickly rejecting another insert of the same key.  That's what my answer says, if you'd like to read it ;-P.

Comment: But unordered_map isn't unordered_multimap.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: agreed, and so what?