# performance of emplace is worse than check followed by emplace

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, unordered-map, emplace

I have a `std::unordered_map` with a *value_type* that does not have a default constructor so I cannot do the following

```
auto k = get_key();
auto& v = my_map[k];
```

I ended up writing a helper function

```
value_type& get_value(key_type& key)
{
    return std::get<0>(my_map.emplace(
                              std::piecewise_construct,
                              std::forward_as_tuple(key),
                              std::forward_as_tuple(args_to_construct_value)
                      ))->second;
}
```

but the performance was markedly worse (i.e. the value_type's constructor showed up in perf) than the following version.

```
value_type& get_value(key_type& key)
{
    auto it = my_map.find(key);
    if (it == my_map.end())
        return std::get<0>(my_map.emplace(
                                  std::piecewise_construct,
                                  std::forward_as_tuple(key),
                                  std::forward_as_tuple(args_to_construct_value)
                          ))->second;
    else
        return it->second;
}
```

I read from [std::unordered_map::emplace object creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704706/stdunordered-mapemplace-object-creation) that emplace needs to construct the object in order to see if exists.  But emplace is checking to see if this key value pair exists in the map before it returns.

Am I using emplace the wrong way? Is there a better pattern I should follow that:

1. Won't construct my value_type every lookup (as in my first method)
2. Won't do the check for to see if value_type exists in my map twice (as in my second method)

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the second approach with [emplace_hint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace_hint)?

Comment: @nosid: Because that requires you to have a hint, which he does not have.  All he has is an `end` iterator

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I haven't the foggiest idea where one could reliably get a hint for an _unordered_ map.  I know you can use `lower_bound` for a map, but I'm not sure if that works for unordered or not.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Apparently, both _libc++_ and _stdlibc++_ ignore the hint for `std::unordered_map`. Apparently, it is useless for this container.

Comment: @MooingDuck doesn't `lower_bound` requires that the input range is sorted? `std::unordered_map` doesn't qualify.

Comment: @nosid I checked, MSVC2013 also ignores the hint.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800405/when-do-you-use-stdunordered-mapemplace-hint) affirms that emplace hint really _cannot_ be used if the keys does not already exist, and is merely there for API compatability.  (Unrelated, boost also ignores the hint: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is unfortunately optimal for the standard library as it currently is.

The problem is that the `emplace` operation is designed to avoid *copying*, not to avoid unnecessary construction of the mapped type.  In practical terms, what happens is that the implementation allocates and constructs a node, containing the map `value_type` i.e. `pair<const Key, T>`, and *then* hashes the key to determine whether the constructed node can be linked into the container; if this collides then the node is deleted.

As long as `hash` and `equal_to` are not too expensive, your code shouldn't do too much extra work.

An alternative is to use a custom allocator that intercepts 0-argument construction of your mapped type; the problem is that detecting such construction is pretty fiddly:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using Key = int;
struct D {
    D() = delete;
    D(D const&) = delete;
    D(D&&) = delete;
    D(std::string x, int y) { std::cout << "D(" << x << ", " << y << ")\n"; }
};
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = T const*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = T const&;
    template<typename U> struct rebind { using other = A<U>; };
    value_type* allocate(std::size_t n) { return std::allocator<T>().allocate(n); }
    void deallocate(T* c, std::size_t n) { std::allocator<T>().deallocate(c, n); }
    template<class C, class...Args> void construct(C* c, Args&&... args) { std::allocator<T>().construct(c, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    template<class C> void destroy(C* c) { std::allocator<T>().destroy(c); }

    std::string x; int y;
    A(std::string x, int y): x(std::move(x)), y(y) {}
    template<typename U> A(A<U> const& other): x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
    template<class C, class...A> void construct(C* c, std::piecewise_construct_t pc, std::tuple<A...> a, std::tuple<>) {
        ::new((void*)c)C(pc, a, std::tie(x, y)); }
};

int main() {
    using UM = std::unordered_map<Key, D, std::hash<Key>, std::equal_to<Key>, A<std::pair<const Key, D>>>;
    UM um(0, UM::hasher(), UM::key_equal(), UM::allocator_type("hello", 42));
    um[5];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `boost::optional<T>` in order to be able to default construct the mapped type and then assign an initialized `T` to it later.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct MappedType
{
  explicit MappedType(int) {}
};

int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<int, boost::optional<MappedType>> map;
  boost::optional<MappedType>& opt = map[0];
  assert(!opt.is_initialized());
  opt = MappedType(2);
  assert(opt.is_initialized());
  MappedType& v = opt.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

James, you've mostly answered your own question.

You're doing nothing wrong in either implementation. `emplace` simply does more work than `find`, especially when the key already exists in your `unordered_map`.

If your `get_value` helper function mostly receives duplicates, then calling `emplace` every time will cause a performance hot spot as you've observed.