# What is the use of emplace_hint in map?

Tags: c++

I understand that map::emplace_hint is used to place a key,value pair at a specified place in the map but in the end the map gets sorted so what is the point of placing it in a certain place?
for example, when i ran this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, int> mymap;
    auto it = mymap.end();
    std::unordered_map<char, int> mymap2;


    it = mymap.emplace_hint(it, 'b', 10);
    mymap.emplace_hint(it, 'z', 12);
    mymap.emplace_hint(mymap.end(), 'a', 14);
    mymap.emplace_hint(mymap.end(), 'c', 10);

    auto it2 = mymap2.end();
    it2 = mymap2.emplace_hint(it2, 'b', 10);
    mymap2.emplace_hint(it2, 'z', 12);
    mymap2.emplace_hint(mymap2.end(), 'a', 14);
    mymap2.emplace_hint(mymap2.end(), 'c', 10);


    std::cout << "mymap contains:";
    for (auto& x : mymap)
        std::cout << " [" << x.first << ':' << x.second << ']';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for(auto& y :mymap2)
        std::cout << " [" << y.first << ':' << y.second << ']';
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

it gave me this o/p :

```
mymap contains: [a:14] [b:10] [c:10] [z:12]
 [z:12] [b:10] [a:14] [c:10]
```

Comment: for the unordered case: [When do you use std::unordered_map::emplace_hint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800405/when-do-you-use-stdunordered-mapemplace-hint)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Suppose you want to insert an element into a map only if the key isn't present yet. You could of course just call `insert`, but suppose further that the operation is expensive or irreversible (e.g. moving from a non-copyable object).

In that situation, you need to separate the lookup from the insertion. That's where the hint comes in, in conjunction with `lower_bound`:

```
auto it = m.lower_bound(key);

if (it != m.end() && it->first == key) {
  // key already exists
} else {
  m.insert(it, std::make_pair(key, compute_expensively()));
  // or:
  m.emplace_hint(it, key, compute_expensively());
}
```

The trick is that `lower_bound` returns the iterator where the key *would* be if it were in the map, regardless of whether it actually is there. The time complexity of the hinted insertion is constant if the hint is correct.

There's no point using the hinted insertion with an incorrect iterator (i.e. one that wasn't obtained as the lower bound for the given key).

Note that hinted insertion only works for *ordered* associative containers. The unordered containers also offer those overloads, but they have no effect, since there is no way to obtain a useful hint for unordered containers.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. So in case of unordered associative containers (`std::unordered_map` in particular), is there currently no way to avoid the performance penalty of finding the element twice? (once when checking if it's there, the other on insertion/emplace)

Comment: @Danra: That's right. Generally, if you thinking "insert if not already there", you want to perform the insertion unconditionally and then just use the return value. In C++17, you can fine-tune this with `try_emplace` and `insert_or_assign`.

Comment: My case is more complex - if the element isn't already found in the map, it should only be inserted pending some further checks. That's why, in my case, the `find` must be split from the `insert`, and why I'm curious about a way to make use of the work already done during `find` to avoid repeating that work during the `insert`.

Comment: @Danra: In general, you can't. But maybe there are other options -- is it worth performing the other tests first? What's the expected usage profile, is there one case that's far more common than the other?

Comment: Perhaps, but I was wondering about the general case, inspired by an open source repo I'm contributing to where I saw this case. I'm wondering if this is worth a standard proposal. What do you think?

Comment: @Danra: Sounds like it's worth thinking about. Look also for existing work in the area; I suspect that it hasn't escaped the original designers' attention that the unordered insertion hints weren't useful; presumably there's an existing discussion of the problems. Just for starters, I could imagine that insertion has to respect the max load factor, so if you need to rehash, your hint isn't useful. Maybe you'd need a guarantee combined with `reserve`. But you'd still not have any way to *obtain* the hint in the first place, i.e. no equivalent of `lower_bound`/`upper_bound`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: Just to be precise, you may really know a meaningful hint for an unordered container. Suppose you are serializing an unordered_set. Chances are you will make it flat by iterating through it. If when you deserialize it, you know for a fact that the same hashing method is used, then you can always use `set.emplace_hint(set.end(), ...)` in a meaningful way

Comment: @KerrekSB You should use `upper_bound` or *increment* the hint before use - but do not use `lower_bound`. It's the same for all instances of `emplace_hint` - they *all* expect the hint to point one *past* the point of insertion. E.g. a sequence of `it = container.erase(it); it = container.emplace_hint(it, ...);` will actually hint correctly, even with containers such as `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 17):

> I understand that map::emplace_hint is used to place a key,value pair at a specified place in the map

No, it isn't.

As you say, you cannot control the position of elements yourself. The map decides that.

This hint is to tell the compiler where you *think* the map will decide to put it, so that the map doesn't have to spend quite as long figuring that out for itself.

For example, if you already know (because it's your program!) that some new element is definitely going to end up at the "start" of the map, then you can pass this knowledge onto the container. It then only needs to check that you're right, instead of scanning through the whole tree to eventually come to that conclusion itself.

If your hint is wrong, that doesn't change anything about where the element ends up, but you're giving the map more work to do.