# what is the use case for using emplace_hint in the case of sets?

Tags: c++, c++11

what is the use case for using emplace_hint in the case of sets ? I gave a hint (s.begin() in the program below) and yet, the emplace_hint seem to be paying no attention to it. Program -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void show(set<string>& s) {
    set<string>::iterator it = s.begin();

    cout << "<" << *it++;
    for (; it != s.end(); it++)
        cout << ", " << *it;
    cout << ">" << endl;
}


set<string>::iterator myEmplaceHint(set<string>::iterator hint_it, set<string> &s, string e) {

    set<string>::iterator ret_it, tmp_it;

    cout << "hint_it :" << *hint_it << endl;
    ret_it = s.emplace_hint(hint_it, e);
    return ret_it;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    set <string> s = { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta" };
    show(s);

    string str("epsilon"), retVal;
    retVal = *myEmplaceHint(s.begin(), s, str);
    cout << "retVal :" << retVal << endl;

    show(s);

    return 0;
}

$ make
g++ -g -Wall -o test test.cpp
$ ./test
<alpha, beta, delta, gamma>
hint_it :alpha
retVal :epsilon
<alpha, beta, delta, epsilon, gamma>
```

Expected the output to be `<alpha, epsilon, beta, delta, gamma>` which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Good hinting just helps improve performance. At first I wrote an incorrect comment here about how much performance improvement. But thinking about it, the complexity will in any case be roughly O(n log n), so we're talking about a constant factor, that depends on the data and the implementation.

Comment: Note that if you don't absolutely need to repeatedly list the items in sorted order, an `unordered_set` gives you O(n) complexity for the insertion of n items.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf would you ellaborate regarding O(nlogn) complexity? Don't we get O(1) if we provide correct hint?

Comment: Since the `set` has to be able to produce a sorted sequence of items, it necessarily uses a data structure where the items are sorted. In practice that means a balanced tree of some kind. For already sorted items a perfect hint will exclude all of the existing tree, because the last node added must be rightmost, but adding the new node then involves (I think that will be in about half of cases) rebalancing of the tree. And rebalancing is an O(log n) operation.

Comment: duplicate of [What is the use of emplace\_hint in map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507671/what-is-the-use-of-emplace-hint-in-map) (yes, I know you asked about `set`, but they use the same data structure in practice; a set is just a map with only a key, no value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `std::set` always stores items in the order specified by the comparison type. This defaults to `std::less`, which means that items will by default always be ascending order. It does not matter what you hint at, the set guarantees to maintain order.
2. emplace_hint is designed to avoid searching the set again if you already know where the item should be inserted.

A very trivial example:

```
#include <set>
#include <cassert>

void ensure_present(std::set<int>& s, int v)
{
    // finding the upper bound is O(logN)
    auto i = s.upper_bound(v);
    if (i == std::end(s) || *i != v) {

        // this would be inefficient since we'd be performing another redundant 
        // O(logN) search for the insertion point
        // s.emplace(v);

        // since we already have the position close to were it should go, we
        // can avoid another search
        s.emplace_hint(i, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a note to your second point to the effect that "Implementations
are permitted to ignore the hint."

Comment: Agree ! on set set<size_t> s = {23, 45, 21, 87, 5, 33, 86, 73}; I tried to it = s.find(87); s.emplace_hint(it, 22); , but it still inserts after 21.

Comment: _emplace_hint is designed to avoid searching the set again if you already know where the item should be inserted._ Does it mean that if we provide it a bad hint there will be a performance impact ?

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan That will be implementation defined. In reality the worst impact you should expect is that the hint is ignored and the search starts from the root of the tree. i.e. it reverts back to O(logN)